# ubuntu 21.04 fstab cifs mount on boot throws 112 with _netdev

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, cifs

So I have an ubuntu machine running 20.04.2 LTS and I am mounting to a Synology NAS with following fstab entry.

```
//10.50.10.20/foo /mnt/foodir/foomountpoint cifs credentials=/home/foo/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,vers=3,noperm,idsfromsid,rw,setuids,handlecache,soft,_netdev 0 0
```

It works just fine.   I setup a new machine with new hardware running 21.04 and the same command is not working. After 30 minutes trying different options, the following entry works.

```
//10.50.10.20/foo /mnt/foodir/foomountpoint cifs credentials=/home/foo/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,vers=3,noperm,idsfromsid,rw,setuids,handlecache,soft,noauto,x-systemd.automount 0 0
```

Can anyone explain why the paraemeter _netdev stop working?

I have been using the same mount command for 3 years, and it seems weird that has stopped working. Dmesg was showing 112 errors for CIFS with the old command.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, it could be the kernel version each Ubuntu's, do they have both same kernel? You might check this link out [about netdev](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169697/how-does-netdev-mount-option-in-etc-fstab-work)